# when do you prefer asterisk param over options hash in ruby method signature

Tags: ruby

When is it more appropriate to write a ruby method signature like this

```
def truncate(text, *values)
```

over

```
def truncate(text, options = {})
```

Both seem to been common at [rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb)

Comment: They do entirely different things so it is a little unclear what you're asking. `*values` puts all the trailing arguments into an array called `values` so you can say `m(x, 1, 2, 3, 4)`. `options = { }` just means that the second argument is optional and defaults to an empty hash so you can say `m(x)` or `m(x, a: 11)` (but you can also cause problems with things like `m(x, 42)`). You also forget `def m(x, **opts)` which is sort of a tighter version of `options = { }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the asterisk parameter when I need to get a bunch of something, like a bunch of numbers or a bunch of strings.

I pass or accept a hash when I need a collection of values that are differentiated by identifying keys.